# AttributeError: module 'bs4' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup4'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import requests,os,bs4
url='http://xkcd.com'
os.makedirs('xkcd',exist_ok=True)
while not url.endswith('#'):
    print('Загружается страница %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup4(res.text)
    comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
    if comicElem == []:
        print('Не удалось найти изображение комиска.')
    else:
        comicUrl = comicElem[0].get('src')
        print('Загружается изображение %s...' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename()
        (comicUrl)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.close()
        prevLink = soup.select('a[rel]="prev"')[0]
        url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
print('Готово.')
```

The error I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'bs4' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup4'
```

Comment: It's not `BeautifulSoup4`, its just `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

The class is named `BeautifulSoup` (without the `4`). So this line:

```py
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup4(res.text)
```

Should become:

```py
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
```